# Amazon S3 Best Practices

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm making a flickr like site and I was wondering if it was possible to have every image stored and retireved in/from S3?

If so, is there any best practice or learned lessons you can pass on?

Thanks

Comment: What language are you working with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, S3 is well suited to store images for a 'Flickr-like' site.

Understand what the repercussions of [choosing bucket names](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html) are. It's no fun to move millions of files between buckets.

For busy sites, you can easily add [ClouldFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) to gain a robust CDN network and lower data charges.

Consider using EC2 for your app servers; there are no data transfer charges between EC2 and S3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

After you sign up for Amazon services, you should download AWS SDK's:
[AWS SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet), [the AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava)

Documentation and Samples are included inside the SDK. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Alsways check for an errors. Always. Repeat request if needed.
Sometimes error rates of S3 API are raised, and Your application should handle this properly.